# Is there a way to record Google Meet live captions

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-hangouts, google-meet

Google Meet (web, in particular) has live captions

Is there any way to record (and save) this [whole/full] meeting transcript?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in feature that records Google Meet captions automatically. Once the captions are no longer on screen, they're effectively gone.

There are numerous browser extensions that record Google Meet captions. I have used some of the existing solutions. However, many were unusually big in app size, was distracting during a meeting, had vague privacy policy, and required manual steps to save the captions each and every time.

I wanted a solution that addressed all of the above. And so I decided to build one.

Chrome Store Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meet-transcript/jkdogkallbmmdhpdjdpmoejkehfeefnb?hl=en

Product Page Link: https://thanesh.dev/meet-transcript.

The transcripts are stored in a Google Docs file in Google Drive and are named after the meeting start time, so you can easily sort through prior transcripts.  These files are the only files that Meet Transcript has access to in Google Drive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not using Meet and the natural language processing it provides directly.
Even if you record a meeting, [captions are not recorded and don't appear when you play the recording.](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9300310?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

What you can do is record the meeting, [download that recording](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9308681?hl=en&ref_topic=7290350), and then use some third party app to create a full transcript from that video. For example, you could upload to youtube, and then see the transcript based off of their processing.

There is also a chrome extension called [Tactiq](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tactiq-for-hangouts-meet/fggkaccpbmombhnjkjokndojfgagejfb) that can save a full meeting transcription. However, the processing Tactiq uses is not the same one Meet uses.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't think getting the captions from the Google Meet web app would not be too hard. It's just about setting up a JS MutationObserver to observe changes being made to the captions <div> the web app provides.

Luckily, I didn't have to make the extension myself; others have already made them for us to use!

You might want to check out [Google Meet Transcripts](https://github.com/dzaman/google-meet-transcripts) (or the Chrome Web Store version [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-meet-transcripts/cjakihmakleeghohchkmkalfoikdnadc)).

[Meet Transcript](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meet-transcript/jkdogkallbmmdhpdjdpmoejkehfeefnb) is not open source, but it is also an option to consider.

And, as a previous answer already mentioned, [Tactiq](https://tactiq.io/) is available on the Chrome Web Store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tactiq-for-google-meet/fggkaccpbmombhnjkjokndojfgagejfb).

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Meet Transcripts currently has a two-star rating in the Chrome Web Store, because it doesn't work well.

Comment: Try using this one instead https://thanesh.dev/meet-transcript

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't allow you to download the captions from a Google Meet meeting.

As another answer mentioned, they do allow you to record the meeting. This could pair nicely with a transcription service.

In that case, you can use a 3rd party service like [Scribbl](https://scribbl.co) to join your meeting and record / transcribe it for you.

Some people don't have the option to record their meetings because the setting is turned off in the g-suite admin.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about the text version? Then yes, Chrome extension [Tactiq Pins for Google Meet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fggkaccpbmombhnjkjokndojfgagejfb) saves the live captures and provides few export options: `.TXT` file or sync it with the meeting notes.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't allow you to download the captions from a Google Meet meeting.

As another answer mentioned, they do allow you to record the meeting. This could pair nicely with a transcription service.

In that case, you can use a 3rd party service like Tactiq to join your meeting and record / transcribe it for you.

Some people don't have the option to record their meetings because the setting is turned off in the g-suite admin.

It also allows you to highlight the transcript and get a summary in google docs.

It's super handy https://tactiq.io/

Answer (score 0):

Try Laxis. It has unlimited real time transcription for the whole meeting. With one click, you can tag all the highlights. Download into word, pdf and etc. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laxis-unlimited-transcrip/pmnibbpdcnkkmakpgmibhlibmdahlpko

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a very useful tool which is called Noty, it exports the entire transcript, currently only for English, using the Google Translate algorithm, perhaps even the paid version of the Google Translate speech-to-text algorithm.

The [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/noty-google-meet-transcri/kdkohcmkkplmkknlelglhfhjkegkiljd) features direct transcription of your entire meeting which can be exported to Google Docs, Slack, other services with a complete integration for meeting attendees to have direct transcription sent through Google Calendar integration.

Imagine you are an English teacher with Google Workspace, and boom.

This extension has made my life so much easier.